# Javascript: How can I chain conditionals?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

Can you help me with this?

```
x = 2 + 2;
y = 1 + 3;

a = 5 + 5;
b = 7 + 3;

///How can I do this: 
if (x == 4 && y == 4 and a == 10 && b == 10) {
  console.log("you are correct!");
}

///Instead of this: 
if (x == 4 && y == 4) {
  console.log("you are correct!");
}

if (a == 10 && y == 10) {
  console.log("you are correct!");
}
```

Comment: Please replace the image with a text-based [mcve]

Comment: Why are you asking if you can do something you're already doing? "and" is `&&` in JS. Since `y` cannot be both `4` and `10` I assume you meant `||` which means OR.

Comment: Because I'm learning. Im new at coding and new to this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this

```
if((x == 4 && y == 4) || (a == 10 && b == 10)){
    console.log("you are correct!")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are meant to use && operator for AND and || for OR:

[AND operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND)

[OR operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR)

Checking your logic, I think you want to use the OR operator ||

Comment: No I don't think they did, since `y` cannot be both 10 and 4. I think they meant `||`

Comment: Just edited the answer, since he was using and in his code, I thought it was the condition that was wrong, not the operator, thanks for pointing that out.